# How to use HttpPostedFileBase in WebApi Model (Post Action)

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

Server side code:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int64 From_UserId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files {get; set;} //<-- Wonder if this is right way ?
}

Action Method in Controller

[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]
public IHttpActionResult Upload( SomeModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    //More code
    return Ok();
}
```

Would angular client code like this work?

```
$http.post("api/upload",{
    Id: 1,
    From_UserId: 1,
    Text: "First File",
    Files: [file1, file2, file3]    //<-These are the ones obtained through file type input 
 })
```

Additional Info: Using Azure Storage to store files uploaded.

Comment: do you need to upload files using AngularJS ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the great directive for it. [**ng-file-upload**](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Here is the [**Demo using Asp.net WebApi**](https://github.com/stewartm83/angular-fileupload-sample).

**JS**

```
//inject directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
    // upload later on form submit or something similar
    $scope.submit = function() {
      if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
        $scope.upload($scope.file);
      }
    };

    // upload on file select or drop
    $scope.upload = function (file) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'upload/url',
            data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
        });
    };
    // for multiple files:
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
      if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          Upload.upload({..., data: {file: files[i]}, ...})...;
        }
        // or send them all together for HTML5 browsers:
        Upload.upload({..., data: {file: files}, ...})...;
      }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I am more concerned about the server side of things. I don't really need `ng-file-upload`, can do without it. As in the question, I would like to post multiple files with other data in model. If you can demonstrate how webapi model can be used for this, it would be great.

Comment: You can use it to post multiple files too.I have put a WebApi demo link also.Please see that too.

Comment: I saw the link you posted. However, in that the files are not posted as a part of webapi model.

Comment: It's just a sample.You need to modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: Can u provide some server code not AngularJS @Sampath

Comment: It is there.see the link `Demo using Asp.net WebApi` on above post @EdukondaluThaviti

Comment: @Sampath how can we do it when we need to pass other form data along with image.I have used HttpPostedFileBase but it returns null